# applying a transformation matrix to the image before proceeding with feature extraction

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, transformation, loss-function

In a section of the code, I am attempting to reimplement the commented code in a different manner. Specifically, I am working on applying a transformation matrix to the image before proceeding with feature extraction

```
 def compute_losses(self):
        

        assert self.net_recog.training == False
        trans_m = self.trans_m
        
        # if not self.opt.use_predef_M:
        #     trans_m = estimate_norm_torch(self.pred_lm, self.input_img.shape[-2])

       
       
        # pred_feat = self.net_recog(self.pred_face, trans_m)
        # gt_feat = self.net_recog(self.input_img, self.trans_m)
        # self.loss_feat = self.opt.w_feat * self.compute_feat_loss(pred_feat, gt_feat)
        if not self.opt.use_predef_M:
            trans_m = estimate_norm_torch(self.pred_lm, self.input_img.shape[-2])

       
        pred_feat1 = cv2.transform(self.pred_face, trans_m, None)
        pred_feat = self.net_recog(pred_feat1)
        gt_feat1 = cv2.transform(self.input_img, trans_m, None)
        gt_feat = self.net_recog(gt_feat1)
        self.loss_feat = self.opt.w_feat * self.compute_feat_loss(pred_feat, gt_feat)
```

I have used cv2.transform but it didn't work. Thank you in advance.

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'transform'
> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix Pytorch tensors and operations with operations from OpenCV. To build the computational graph and for operations to be differentiable you can only work with Pytorch operations. You can use for example a combination of [grid_sample](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.grid_sample.html) and [affine_grid](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.affine_grid.html#torch.nn.functional.affine_grid) to apply a transformation matrix to an image in Pytorch.